# Change Custom ListView Item programmatically

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom listview with three items. One of them is like "Add this to the DB" and when I click to it it inserts something to the DB.

What I want it to do is after doing the insert, change the text to "Delete this from the DB" and also the `onClick` method to call a method to delete that record instead a method to insert.
Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
final String[] opcs = new String[]{"Resultados", "Clasificación", text_fav};

      ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_menutipo_item, opcs);
      m_list.setAdapter(aa);          
      m_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                Intent newActivity = null;
                switch( position )
                {                  
                    case 0:  ...


                    case 2:  if (isConnected(m_context))
                     {
                        añadirFavorito();
                     }
                    break;  
                }
            }   
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible. The view parameter to the `onItemClick` callback is the view on which you clicked, you can simply change that view's content. i.e. `view.setText("Delete this from the DB")`.

Also you will want to distinguish whether the next click is "Add this to the DB" or "Delete this from the DB", doing a string comparison here like `if("Delete this from the DB".equals(view.getText()))` might not be of good practice, you can set a flag in the view like `view.setTag(true)` to indicate that the current view's content is "Delete this from the DB". and later you can use `view.getTag()` to get back the flag to do the comparison.

```
Boolean flag = (Boolean)view.getTag();
if(flag == null || !flag) {
    view.setText("Delete this from the DB");
    flag = true;
    //... code to insert a record to DB
} else {
    view.setText("Insert this to the DB");
    flag = false;
    //... code to delete a record from DB
}
view.setTag(flag);
```